# Alterations {in/to} the plan

Tags: prepositions, tense

Could you please tell me which one is correct and why?

> I did some alterations in the plan.
>
> I did some alterations to the plan.

Also,
Can I say it as following? :

> I made some alterations in the plan.
>
> I made some alterations to the plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All four are understandable as you **making changes** to a plan

> 1) I **did** some alterations **in** the plan
>   2) I **did** some alterations **to** the plan
>   3) I **made** some alterations **in** the plan
>   4) I **made** some alterations **to** the plan

From my experience #3 and #4 are usually used
To an AmE ear, **changes** is usually used in place of **alterations**, alterations are usually **modifications** made to a piece of clothing in which case **to** is used

> I made some **changes** in our *travel* plans
>   I made some **alterations** to the dress

Comment: Also, to my AmE ear, "I did some alterations/changes" sounds like foreign English to me. Though it may be grammatically correct, it doesn't sound right. You don't "do" changes, you "make" changes...you effect the change, you don't actually act out the change yourself

Comment: +1 This would be along the lines of: "I **did** a few things **to change** the plan"